# Handle attachment in response with RequestBuilder in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, pdf, attachment

I am making a HTTP POST request from GWT Client to a HTTPServlet. This Servlet is creating a PDF file from request content and writing it to response stream.

Headers of the response stream are:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.pdf
```

I want to open this PDF in new window of the user's browser or prompt him to download it.

```
import com.google.gwt.http.client.*;
...

String url = "http://www.myserver.com/getData?type=3";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, URL.encode(url));

try {
  Request request = builder.sendRequest(data, new RequestCallback() {
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
       // Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP violation, etc.)     
    }

    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
      if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
          // Process the response in response.getText()
          // Window.open(url, "_blank", "");
      } else {
        // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
      }
    }       
  });
} catch (RequestException e) {
  // Couldn't connect to server        
}
```

How should I handle response in onResponseRecieved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think in this case you should not use a single `RequestBuilder` AJAX call. You can rely on the default browser behavior by invoking a normal call and letting the browser handle the PDF response (displaying it with a PDF viewer plugin or opening a Save dialog).

There are several alternatives to achieving this:

1. If you can pass your data in a GET request (only possible for a small data volume) you can create the URL with the data as GET parameters and then open a new browser window with [Window.open()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) passing the URL with data.
2. For larger amounts of data you can first POST your data with `RequestBuilder` to the server to store the data temporaly and in [RequestCallback.onResponseReceived()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestCallback.html#onResponseReceived%28com.google.gwt.http.client.Request,%20com.google.gwt.http.client.Response%29) open a new browser window with a short URL like above in alternative 1. On the server side you have to split the PDF generation servlet into two parts: a data store servlet with POST method (i.e. storing the data into the web session) and a PDF render servlet with GET method, which takes the data out of the session (and deleting it) and doesn't need large parameters.
3. Create a form with method POST, hidden fields for your data and the PDF generation servlet URL. Fill the hidden fields with your data and submit the form programmatically (i.e. [FormPanel.submit()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#submit%28%29)). If you create your `FormPanel` with a [target name](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#FormPanel%28java.lang.String%29) the browser opens a new window or uses the specified frame to handle the response.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side, use an Anchor instead of a request builder and invoke the servlet directly
by using Window.Location.replace(URL.encode(formActionUrl));