# Can servlet call browser native dialog box from response?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, pdf, apache-poi

I have [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) + [Ext GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) project, which can produce some charts.

Recently, I've added some ***Export buttons for Excel([ApachePOI](http://poi.apache.org/)) and pdf([wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)).***

What I want:

1. ***Simple and more efficient request call from client code*** It's much preferable *TODO* in doPOST method, cause in near future I should send more than 1024kBytes Data parameters. *I'm not sure about my request especially with calling 2 method (GET, after receiving POST), [which inspired from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282987/handle-attachment-in-response-with-requestbuilder-in-gwt/7287574#7287574).*
2. ***Be sure*** what my Servlet methods is efficient also.
3. ***Open Browser's native dialogbox*** every time. It's opened by default only for *.xls*-files. As I saw it's possible for *.pdf*-files, I'd asked [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539677/browsers-native-dialogbox-for-pdf-files).

---

1. From client code click listener for **request** looks like this:

**Should I play more with MIME types?*

```
String fileExtension ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
if (extension.equals("pdf"))
{
    sURLforRequest = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "requiredPDF";
    fileExtension = "application/pdf";
}
else if (extension.equals("xls"))
{
    sURLforRequest = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "requiredXLS";
    fileExtension = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}

RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, sURLforRequest);
//this is important
builder.setHeader("Content-type", fileExtension);
//builder.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//builder.setHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

builder.sendRequest(sData, new RequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        //TODO: replace with servleet link
        Window.open(sURLforRequest, "_parent", "location=no");

    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        MessageBox.alert("Request error","The page doesn't open", null);
    }
});
```

And as you see, I've send some *Data in POST request and call GET method to show Server-generated file* in blank (*If you have better idea How to organize this, please share*).

2. My Servlet used *HttpSession* for share *Data parameters* between *doGET* and *doPOST* methods, and for possible appropriate answer for several user which call Servlet in the same time:

**for the moment nothing special*

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException
{
    try {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        session = request.getSession();

        //global
        session.setAttribute("vDateFrom",request.getParameter("vDateFrom"));
        ...
        session.setAttribute("vChartType",request.getParameter("vChartType"));

        //doPost(request,resp);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

3. doGet method that doing a lot of work:

**Cause I call servlet again with window.open() method from client side it feels like nothing is happen (that's of course too bad)*

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    try {

        //CreateHtmlFile();
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        lDateFrom = Long.parseLong(request.getSession().getAttribute("vDateFrom").toString());
        ...

        CreateHtmlFile(...);

        ConvertHTMLtoPDF(servletContext.getRealPath("wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe"),
                servletContext.getRealPath("PDFtemplate/requiredPDF.html"),
                servletContext.getRealPath("PDFtemplate/Report.pdf"));

        //Now I have required .pdf-files, 
        //BUT HOW TO SEND IT TO CLIENT SIDE WITH BROWSER ASK WHAT TODO

        //I used to call this before, but it seems not so correct
        //response.sendRedirect(servletContext.getRealPath("PDFtemplate/Report.pdf"));

        //What is I'm thinking about
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(servletContext.getRealPath("XLStemplate/reportXLS.xlsx")));

        response.setContentType("application/pdf; charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"), true);

        char[] buf = new char[4 * 1024]; // 4Kchar buffer
        int len;
        while ((len = reader.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.flush();

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I took one servlet for pdf, write some comments where I have problem or not sure about.

---

So my troubles are:

1. Use one request from client side
2. Do it more efficient without any behaviour doing nothing
3. Send file to client side where browser show what todo dialog (open
   or save and ok or cancel)?

---

Comment: *"(Big, Important and Interesting)"*  What is?

Comment: It's a bug, I forgot to delete

Comment: I've found solution to send file with browser show dialogue from [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/send-files-from-servlet-to-client-for-downloading).